# Angular routing child lazy module

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing, angular4-router

I am using Angular 4 with routing for Lazy/shared module.

Here How can I use path without my lazy module name appended in URL?

Currently my `partner` component accessible with `http://localhost:4200/#/main/partner` but I want to use same with URL `http://localhost:4200/#/partner`. Without appending `/main` to my compenent.

Same for `dashboard`, `employeelist` and `addemployee`, I want to access directly with `localhost:4200/#/dashboard` and so.

Here below is my App-Routing and lazy-Routing files.

> app.routing.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'emailLogin/forgotpassword', component: ForgotPasswordComponent },
  { path: 'forgotpassword', component: ForgotPasswordComponent },
  { path: 'login', redirectTo: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'main', loadChildren: './lazy.module#LazyModule' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/main' }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true });
```

> lazy.routing.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthguardGuardPartnerUser] },
  { path: 'partner', component: PartnerComponent, canActivate: [AuthguardGuard] },
  { path: 'employeelist', component: EmployeeComponent, canActivate: [AuthguardGuardPartnerUser] },
  { path: 'addemployee', component: AddemployeeComponent, canActivate: [AuthguardGuardPartnerUser] },
  { path: 'newsurvey/:neworcopy', component: NewsurveyComponent, canActivate: [AuthguardGuardAdminPartner] },
  // .... Other components
  { path: '404pageNotFound', component: NotfoundComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/404pageNotFound' }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured it out just change

```
{ path: '', loadChildren: './lazy.module#LazyModule' },
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
```

in `app.routing.ts` solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know that you cannot have the same route load two different things, so you need to restructure. There are 3 ways you could do this that I can think of.

**Option 1**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'emailLogin/forgotpassword', component: ForgotPasswordComponent },
  { path: 'forgotpassword', component: ForgotPasswordComponent },
  { path: 'login', redirectTo: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'partner', loadChildren: './lazy.module#LazyModule' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/main' }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true });

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: PartnerComponent, canActivate: [AuthguardGuard] },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthguardGuardPartnerUser] },
  { path: '404pageNotFound', component: NotfoundComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/404pageNotFound' }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

This will load the lazy module at `/partner`, and then since the first route inside your lazy module is now '', it will load the partner component. But obviously this means your dashboard is now `/partner/dashboard`.

**Option 2**

Alternatively, move the partner component out of the lazy module and into your app module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'emailLogin/forgotpassword', component: ForgotPasswordComponent },
  { path: 'forgotpassword', component: ForgotPasswordComponent },
  { path: 'login', redirectTo: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'partner', component: PartnerComponent, canActivate: [AuthguardGuard] },
  { path: 'main', loadChildren: './lazy.module#LazyModule' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/main' }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true });

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthguardGuardPartnerUser] },
  { path: '404pageNotFound', component: NotfoundComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/404pageNotFound' }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

**Option 3**

Or just move the partner component into its own module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'emailLogin/forgotpassword', component: ForgotPasswordComponent },
  { path: 'forgotpassword', component: ForgotPasswordComponent },
  { path: 'login', redirectTo: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'main', loadChildren: './lazy.module#LazyModule' },
  { path: 'partner', loadChildren: './partner.module#PartnerModule' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/main' }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true });

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthguardGuardPartnerUser] },
  { path: '404pageNotFound', component: NotfoundComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/404pageNotFound' }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

> partner.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: PartnerComponent, canActivate: [AuthguardGuard] },
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

I suspect the 3rd option is probably most suitable as it keeps all your current routes the same, and provides a bit more flexibility going forward.

Comment: in Option 1, Can I restructure to use `/partner` for partner and `/dashboard` for dashboard module?

Comment: Yes, just move the /dashboard route and component into your app module and out of the lazy module. Or create a dashboard module  (which is what I would do, as you will most likely add more components to the dashboard module later)